# How to prove that add one of the deleted rows and columns to the matrix will not increase the polynomial degree of GCD of largest minors more than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, control-theory

$\textbf{A}$ is a $N \times N$ matrix and $\textbf{B}$ is a $N \times M$ matrix. The polynomial degree of greatest common divisor of the largest minors of matrix $[\textbf{A}-\lambda \textbf{I} \quad \textbf{B}]$ is $0$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. If add one column and one row to matrix $\textbf{A}$ to get the matrix $[\textbf{A}_1-\lambda \textbf{I} \quad \textbf{B}_1]$, how to prove that the polynomial degree of greatest common divisor of the largest minors of matrix $[\textbf{A}_1-\lambda \textbf{I} \quad \textbf{B}_1]$ smaller than 2?

For example,
$$
  \textbf{A} = \left(
     \matrix{0 & 0\cr a_{21} & 0} 
  \right) 
$$

$$
  \textbf{B} = \left(
     \matrix{b_1 \cr 0} 
  \right) 
$$
Add one column and row to $\textbf{A}$ to get $[\textbf{A}_1-\lambda \textbf{I} \quad \textbf{B}_1]$ as
$$
  \left(
     \matrix{-\lambda & 0 & a_{13} & b_1\cr a_{21} & -\lambda & a_{23} & 0 \cr  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}-\lambda & b_3} 
  \right) 
$$